# Scrolling text animation on one background

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/pages/main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">

        <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="background-clip">
            <source src="../images/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div class="section" id="anchoredCtaWeb">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>Hello World</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>
              <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>
              <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>

              <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>
          </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    height: 600vh;
  }
  
  #anchoredCtaWeb {
    position: sticky;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 10px;
  }
  
  #anchoredCtaWeb.show {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

.background-clip{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    .background-clip{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    .background-clip{
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    const anchoredCtaWeb = document.getElementById("anchoredCtaWeb");
    if (window.pageYOffset > 817) {
      anchoredCtaWeb.classList.add("show");
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset < 817) {
      anchoredCtaWeb.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
```

I want a text animation that when i scroll the first text dissapear and the other text appears on the same background like the website shown in the link below:
https://www.groupamana.com/
in this website in the video section u can see how when we scroll the firs text dissapear and the second text appears i want exactly the same one

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/pages/main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">

        <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="background-clip">
            <source src="../images/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div class="section" id="anchoredCtaWeb">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>Hello World</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>
              <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>
              <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>

              <div class="container">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                
              </div>
          </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    height: 600vh;
  }
  
  #anchoredCtaWeb {
    position: sticky;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 10px;
  }
  
  #anchoredCtaWeb.show {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

.background-clip{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    .background-clip{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    .background-clip{
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    const anchoredCtaWeb = document.getElementById("anchoredCtaWeb");
    if (window.pageYOffset > 817) {
      anchoredCtaWeb.classList.add("show");
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset < 817) {
      anchoredCtaWeb.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
```

I want a text animation that when i scroll the first text dissapear and the other text appears on the same background like the website shown in the link below:
https://www.groupamana.com/
in this website in the video section u can see how when we scroll the firs text dissapear and the second text appears i want exactly the same one

I want a text animation that when i scroll the first text dissapear and the other text appears on the same background like the website shown in the link below:
https://www.groupamana.com/
in this website in the video section u can see how when we scroll the firs text dissapear and the second text appears i want exactly the same one

Answer (score 0):

This example may helps you.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--scroll',window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight));
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 500vh;
  background-color: rgb(255 252 237);
  animation: body 1s linear;
}
@keyframes body {
  to {
    background-color: rgb(221 158 65);
  }
}

.progress {
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: progress 1s linear;
}
@keyframes progress {
  to {
    background-color: rgb(90 24 24);
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.cube-wrap {
  --size: 30vmin;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  perspective: 100vmin;
}
.cube {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(45deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  animation: cube 1s linear;
}
@keyframes cube {
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(45deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  }
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background-color: #eee;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  top: calc(var(--size) * -.5);
  left: calc(var(--size) * -.5);
}
.top {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(calc(var(--size) * .5));
}
.bottom {
  background-color: #999;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(calc(var(--size) * -.5));
}
.left {
  background-color: #ccc;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(calc(var(--size) * .5));
}
.right {
  background-color: #ddd;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(calc(var(--size) * -.5));
}
.front {
  background-color: #aaa;
  transform: translateZ(calc(var(--size) * .5));
}
.back {
  background-color: #bbb;
  transform: translateZ(calc(var(--size) * -.5));
}

:root * {
  /* Pause the animation */
  animation-play-state: paused;
  /* Bind the animation to scroll */
  animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
  /* These last 2 properites clean up overshoot weirdness */
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>

<div class="cube-wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side top"></div>
    <div class="side bottom"></div>
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but u send the code at the same sample in the link i sent  because i tried to make it and it didnt work